# Check uncheck checkbox in Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

I have a json response as

```
{"roles":[{"id":1,"name":"Super Administrator","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","permissions":[{"id":1,"name":"user create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":1}},{"id":2,"name":"user edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":2}},{"id":3,"name":"user view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":3}},{"id":4,"name":"user delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":4}},{"id":5,"name":"role_permission view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":5}},{"id":6,"name":"role_permission edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":6}},{"id":7,"name":"accounthead create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":7}},{"id":8,"name":"accounthead edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":8}},{"id":9,"name":"accounthead view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":9}},{"id":10,"name":"accounthead delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":10}},{"id":11,"name":"journal create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":11}},{"id":12,"name":"journal edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":12}},{"id":13,"name":"journal view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":13}},{"id":14,"name":"journal delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":14}},{"id":15,"name":"vendor create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":15}},{"id":16,"name":"vendor edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":16}},{"id":17,"name":"vendor view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":17}},{"id":18,"name":"vendor delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":18}},{"id":19,"name":"itemcategory create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":19}},{"id":20,"name":"itemcategory edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":20}},{"id":21,"name":"itemcategory view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":21}},{"id":22,"name":"itemcategory delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":22}},{"id":23,"name":"item create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":23}},{"id":24,"name":"item edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":24}},{"id":25,"name":"item view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":25}},{"id":26,"name":"item delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","pivot":{"role_id":1,"permission_id":26}}]},{"id":2,"name":"Administrator","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","permissions":[]},{"id":3,"name":"Accounts","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","permissions":[]},{"id":4,"name":"Cashier","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","permissions":[]},{"id":5,"name":"Teacher","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","permissions":[]},{"id":6,"name":"Student","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","permissions":[]}],"permissions":[{"id":1,"name":"user create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":2,"name":"user edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":3,"name":"user view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":4,"name":"user delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":5,"name":"role_permission view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":6,"name":"role_permission edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":7,"name":"accounthead create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":8,"name":"accounthead edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":9,"name":"accounthead view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":10,"name":"accounthead delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":11,"name":"journal create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":12,"name":"journal edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":13,"name":"journal view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":14,"name":"journal delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":15,"name":"vendor create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":16,"name":"vendor edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":17,"name":"vendor view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":18,"name":"vendor delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":19,"name":"itemcategory create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":20,"name":"itemcategory edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:33.000000Z"},{"id":21,"name":"itemcategory view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z"},{"id":22,"name":"itemcategory delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z"},{"id":23,"name":"item create","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z"},{"id":24,"name":"item edit","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z"},{"id":25,"name":"item view","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z"},{"id":26,"name":"item delete","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-07T14:51:34.000000Z"}],"rolePermissions":{"Super Administrator":{"user create":true,"user edit":true,"user view":true,"user delete":true,"role_permission view":true,"role_permission edit":true,"accounthead create":true,"accounthead edit":true,"accounthead view":true,"accounthead delete":true,"journal create":true,"journal edit":true,"journal view":true,"journal delete":true,"vendor create":true,"vendor edit":true,"vendor view":true,"vendor delete":true,"itemcategory create":true,"itemcategory edit":true,"itemcategory view":true,"itemcategory delete":true,"item create":true,"item edit":true,"item view":true,"item delete":true},"Administrator":{"user create":false,"user edit":false,"user view":false,"user delete":false,"role_permission view":false,"role_permission edit":false,"accounthead create":false,"accounthead edit":false,"accounthead view":false,"accounthead delete":false,"journal create":false,"journal edit":false,"journal view":false,"journal delete":false,"vendor create":false,"vendor edit":false,"vendor view":false,"vendor delete":false,"itemcategory create":false,"itemcategory edit":false,"itemcategory view":false,"itemcategory delete":false,"item create":false,"item edit":false,"item view":false,"item delete":false},"Accounts":{"user create":false,"user edit":false,"user view":false,"user delete":false,"role_permission view":false,"role_permission edit":false,"accounthead create":false,"accounthead edit":false,"accounthead view":false,"accounthead delete":false,"journal create":false,"journal edit":false,"journal view":false,"journal delete":false,"vendor create":false,"vendor edit":false,"vendor view":false,"vendor delete":false,"itemcategory create":false,"itemcategory edit":false,"itemcategory view":false,"itemcategory delete":false,"item create":false,"item edit":false,"item view":false,"item delete":false},"Cashier":{"user create":false,"user edit":false,"user view":false,"user delete":false,"role_permission view":false,"role_permission edit":false,"accounthead create":false,"accounthead edit":false,"accounthead view":false,"accounthead delete":false,"journal create":false,"journal edit":false,"journal view":false,"journal delete":false,"vendor create":false,"vendor edit":false,"vendor view":false,"vendor delete":false,"itemcategory create":false,"itemcategory edit":false,"itemcategory view":false,"itemcategory delete":false,"item create":false,"item edit":false,"item view":false,"item delete":false},"Teacher":{"user create":false,"user edit":false,"user view":false,"user delete":false,"role_permission view":false,"role_permission edit":false,"accounthead create":false,"accounthead edit":false,"accounthead view":false,"accounthead delete":false,"journal create":false,"journal edit":false,"journal view":false,"journal delete":false,"vendor create":false,"vendor edit":false,"vendor view":false,"vendor delete":false,"itemcategory create":false,"itemcategory edit":false,"itemcategory view":false,"itemcategory delete":false,"item create":false,"item edit":false,"item view":false,"item delete":false},"Student":{"user create":false,"user edit":false,"user view":false,"user delete":false,"role_permission view":false,"role_permission edit":false,"accounthead create":false,"accounthead edit":false,"accounthead view":false,"accounthead delete":false,"journal create":false,"journal edit":false,"journal view":false,"journal delete":false,"vendor create":false,"vendor edit":false,"vendor view":false,"vendor delete":false,"itemcategory create":false,"itemcategory edit":false,"itemcategory view":false,"itemcategory delete":false,"item create":false,"item edit":false,"item view":false,"item delete":false}}}
```

And, i have popuplated the form based on this value as below screenshot. 
[Now, i need to check or uncheck the checkbox based on the value under rolePermissions field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xybb.png)

Below is my code from vue

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>                  
      <tr>
      <th>Permissions</th>
      <th v-for="role in permissions.roles" :key="role.id">{{ role.name }}</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr v-for="permission in permissions.permissions" :key="permission.id">
          <td>{{ permission.name }}</td>
          <td v-for="role in permissions.roles" :key="role.id">
              <input type="checkbox" :name="'role_permission['+ permission.name +']['+ role.name +']'" />                               
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: please post only minimal required data

Comment: To dynamicaly check or uncheck a checkbox with view based on a variable (boolean) you simple include the v-model directive to the input checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically check or uncheck a checkbox with vue based on a variable (boolean) you simple include the v-model directive to the input checkbox.

```
<!-- checked = false || true; -->
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="checked">
```

So in your case it should be :

```
<!-- role_permission[permission.name][role.name] = false || true -->
<input type="checkbox" v-model="role_permission[permission.name][role.name]"/>
```

That is if `role_permission[permission.name][role.name]` is a Boolean value.
Here, from the official docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

Comment: Thanks, it did a trick. Though i had to change some of my code.